# Google Custom search api File not found exception

Tags: android, google-api, google-search-api

I am trying to implement google custom search api. but i am getting the following exception. i dont know why? can anyone help Thanks.

**What i have tried so far**

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    String key = getResources().getString(R.string.search_key);
                    String qry = "Pdf";
                    URL url = null;
                    url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=" + qry + "&cx=009509498206542289642:aac_kxxh3ao&fileType=pdf&key"+key+ "&alt=json");

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            (conn.getInputStream())));

                    String output;
                    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (output.contains("\"link\": \"")) {
                            String link = output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"") + ("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
                            System.out.println(link);       //Will print the google search links
                        }
                    }
                    conn.disconnect();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

**Exception:**

```
04-14 02:26:23.426 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Pdf&cx=009509498206542289642:aac_kxxh3ao&fileType=pdf&keyAIzaSyCOnVh7xMKxQ1yBmYZnY4i0wxQBMJ8vNuE&alt=json
04-14 02:26:23.430 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
04-14 02:26:23.433 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
04-14 02:26:23.446 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at com.pdgproject.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:221)
04-14 02:26:23.450 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at com.pdgproject.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:208)
04-14 02:26:23.450 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-14 02:26:23.456 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-14 02:26:23.460 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-14 02:26:23.460 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-14 02:26:23.463 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-14 02:26:23.463 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-14 02:26:23.466 24867-25162/com.pdgproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**code on line 221**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            (conn.getInputStream())));
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Check the url.

Comment: [...]&keyAIza[...] must be [...]&key=AIza[...]